# Force selection of highlighted p:autoComplete item when panel is hidden by clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a problem (bug?) with my auto-complete.

MyFaces 2.2.9 with PrimeFaces 5.1

This below is only an example to reproduce my error. I have a auto-complete - box in my modal dialog.

1. Case 1 : I type something select "hello" from list in autocomplete
   and submit. Converter gets my person id and search the right person,
   all works fine.
2. Case 2 (Error 1) : I type "h" and click in my modal area the h
   stays and list close. (When I submit my form h only disappears, no
   converter call) But I think h should disappear because force
   selection?
3. Case 3 (Error 2) : The other error is harder. When I type "hello"
   (which is in the list) in my box and click in my modal dialog area,
   hello stays! When I submit the form I get "hello" in my converter
   and get back "null" because he only searches for the ids.

**More for case 3**: I try to explain it with more details (see comments):
I type something in my autocomplete box, with a string, that is in my box.
[image]

than i click in my modal area. (NOT! directly on the choosable hello). Than the hello seems to be accept, too.

[image]

Now i click on my test button and in my converter `public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {` is arg2 not the ID from hello, it is the string "hello". Only the string.

My expected behavior should be that there comes my id. The id comes only when i use the normal selection.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks for your time :)

**Question:** Is this a bug or it is a misunderstanding from me?

XHTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13">
         <p:commandButton value="show Dialog" 
                          oncomplete="PF('dgl').show()"
                          update=":dglform"/>
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="dgl" modal="true" resizable="false">
         <h:form id="dglform" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13">
             <p:autoComplete id="auto"
                             forceSelection="true"
                             converter="personConverter"
                             value="#{myController.selectedPerson}"
                             var="per"
                             itemLabel="#{per.name}"
                             itemValue="#{per}"
                             completeMethod="#{myController.search}">
             </p:autoComplete>

             <p:commandButton value="test" update="@form" />
          </h:form>
      </p:dialog>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter("personConverter")
public class PersonConverter implements Converter{

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
        System.out.println(arg2);

        //Search my entity with id...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        if(arg2 instanceof Person){
            Person p = (Person) arg2;
            return String.valueOf(p.getId());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class MyController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Person selectedPerson;
    private List<Person> persons;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person(1, "hello"));
        persons.add(new Person(2, "hello2"));
    }

    public void selectListener(SelectEvent event){
        System.out.println("SELECT!");
    }

    public Person getSelectedPerson() {
        return selectedPerson;
    }

    public void setSelectedPerson(Person selectedPerson) {
        this.selectedPerson = selectedPerson;
    }

    public List<Person> search(String qry) {
        return persons;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see anything that may be termed, "*unexpected*" or "*bug*". All of those three cases that you listed work normally as you want. What is the question now? 1) "*I type something select "hello" from list in autocomplete and submit. Converter gets my person id and search the right person, all works fine.*" - **nothing to say**. 2) "*But I think h should disappear because of force selection?*" - **yes**. 3) "*When I submit the form, I get "hello" in my converter and get back "null" because he only searches for the ids.*" - **that's not related auto-complete at all**. To be continued.

Comment: It's all depends upon how you construct an instance of `Person` in `getAsObject()` using a scalar value (String to Object conversion) and have it returned by `getAsString()` (Object to String conversion) in turn, when you display.

Comment: I think there is a missunderstanding ;) ... case 2 AND 3 works not as expected. Case 2: the h dont dissapear when i click in my modal area it stays when i click in the form somewhere it works. Case 3: When type a word that is in the autocomplete box and click in the modal area the word stays and give me the string in my converter NOT the same as case1. When i choose something directly in my box.

Comment: I always see everything happening correctly in all three cases you mentioned. When I enter a string which the list bound to the given `<p:autoComplete>` does **not** contain and I click somewhere outside, the string disappears...

Comment: (It is likely that you may be clicking on the area marked/covered by background opacity (because of `<p:dialog modal="true"...>`). That area is actually locked/deactivated. Therefore, the string which you expect to disappear will not disappear on clicking on that locked area. Try clicking outside that area - on the browser's address bar, for example. You should be able to see a thing happening correctly). When I enter a string which is contained by the list bound to the given `<p:autoComplete>`, I always get the corresponding `id` (`itemValue` and not `itemLabel`) in the converter in question.

Comment: " Therefore, the string which you expect to disappear will not disappear on clicking on that locked area. " ... but imo that should be because for a normal user it seems that the value is accepted....  "I always get the corresponding id (itemValue and not itemLabel) in the converter in question" ...sure? When you type something that is in the box,  than click on the locked area from modal than on the button? In my case comes only the input string.... Anyway thanks for your comments, help and time :)

Comment: I tried on JSF 2.3.0-m01 and a released candidate of PrimeFaces (RC 3). I will try using PrimeFaces 5.1 and respond accordingly here later, if the PrimeFaces version makes any discrepancy. I am not sure about MyFaces, if it is the culprit (but presumably both the PrimeFaces version I used and MyFaces should not have a relevance to the problem we are interested in) (The answer to the question mark(s) in the last part of your comment is, "**Yes**". When I click on the button (when the string is contained by the box), I get a corresponding `id` in the converter).

Comment: I tried on Mojarra 2.2.8-02 and PrimeFaces 5.1 final. No change. Perhaps, I did not get the question well. Sorry, the inconvenience caused to you is regretted. Wish you all for other potential answerer(s) :).

Comment: @Tiny: so you can reproduce this issue when clicking in the 'modal' area? Or does it not matter where you click (modal area or url bar) and you see 'good' behaviour?

Comment: @Kukeltje : I see everything happening normally only on my behalf. I am however, completely unsure about this - part of the case 2, "*I type "h" and click in my modal area the h stays and list close.*" I see as it is written and to me, it should because the modal area is actually locked but I am not sure about whether it needs to be altered to something different - whether the OP wants something different to happen. I even lowered the PrimeFaces version to 4.0 in addition to 5.1 and 5.2 with no discrepancy at all. I feel everything happens as it should happen intuitively.

Comment: I get indeed exactly the described behavior. For #2 you should just add `required="true" requiredMessage="Please select existing person"` or so to make it more intuitive. For #3 I'm not sure what the intent is as you explicitly stated that your converter returns null, but it isn't clear if it's just part of omitting "irrelevant" code for the sake of demo, or of your actual problem (but why did you explicitly state that in the question then?)

Comment: okay that is my solution at the moment for case 2 think its the best way for it, to fix the behavior. Thank you. I edit my question on top and try to explain case 3 better, please have a look on it. You are right null is irrelevant code. Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Got it. I reproduced your problem. This is indeed a bug in the JavaScript associated with `<p:autoComplete>`. I haven't inspected its JS yet, but I have the impression that the actual value is only set during click event and not during blur event, so the fix would be rather simple: attach the same listener on blur event too, or at least to the hide event of the menu, if any.

Comment: thank you. I can try it tomorrow. If you want you can send both solutions / comments as an answer and i will accept it :)

Comment: I will look at its JS so I can post a more concrete answer, but not today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not necessarily a bug in PrimeFaces, but likely an oversight in case `forceSelection="true"` is used. You'd somewhat expect the same behavior here as when you press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in the input.

You'd best report this as an [issue](http://www.primefaces.org/issuetracker) to PF guys. In the meanwhile, here's how you can workaround it yourself, assuming PrimeFaces 5.1:

1. Put a copy of [raw source code](https://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/tags/5_1/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/autocomplete/autocomplete.js) of original [`autocomplete.js`](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/5_1/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/autocomplete/autocomplete.js) as `/resources/primefaces/autocomplete/autocomplete.js` in your webapp.
2. Head to [line 170](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/5_1/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/autocomplete/autocomplete.js#170). This is where the hide event of the autocomplete panel is being handled.
3. At line 181, between the second and the third `if` block, insert the below code:

   ```
   if ($this.cfg.forceSelection) {
       $this.items.filter('.ui-state-highlight').click();
   }
   ```

   This will force the highlighted item to be auto-selected when `forceSelection="true"` is used.
4. Load the customized `autocomplete.js` in top of your `<h:body>` (not `<h:head>`!) as below:

   ```
   <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="autocomplete/autocomplete.js" target="head" />
   ```

This is indeed somewhat cumbersome, but as those functions are private, they can't be easily overridden from outside. Also attaching another listener won't work as it's explicitly doing a `$.off()` on any previous listeners.