# Force selection of highlighted p:autoComplete item when panel is hidden by clicking outside in PrimeFaces 6.3

Tags: primefaces

This post solved the problem for PrimeFaces 5.1 : [Force selection of highlighted p:autoComplete item when panel is hidden by clicking outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474817/force-selection-of-highlighted-pautocomplete-item-when-panel-is-hidden-by-click/54072755)

But, how to do that for PrimeFaces 6.3 ?

Comment: What did you try? What did you debug? Any errors?

Comment: I don't really know what to try.
But i found a solution since first post.
I added in 'bindStaticEvents: function()' block the old block of code "//hide overlay when outside is clicked" with included correction.
But replacing autocomplete.js in PrimeFaces 6.3 (like in the link above) generate error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerDynamicOverlay' of undefined" for all line like "PrimeFaces.utils.register...".
If i comment all these line, autocomplete seems to work properly. But i don't know if it's really okay.

Comment: @DamienL you should report this on the PF Issues page so it gets fixed before 6.3 is release.  I think this might be the issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/344

Comment: Looking your issue is slightly different than #344.  I suggest create a new issue on the PF GitHub page so this can be corrected before 6.3 is released.

Comment: Thanks to you.
#344, it's exactly my problem.
But it's for a production environment. To wait, i need to fix that myself.